# How to ignore directories in OpenGrok index?

Tags: opengrok

I am trying to setup OpenGrok to search through a few GB of code, mostly Java and Python projects. I use `opengrok-0.12.1/bin/OpenGrok index $SRC_ROOT` to build the index. I can see it indexing Java's "target" and Python's ".tox" directories which I don't need.

I searched online and found the same question in many forums, and the answer being to use -i. I have tried to use this option with both the OpenGrok wrapper script as well as opengrok.jar, but all I get is the help message (because the command line options were apparently wrong).

Could you give me an example command to build indices that ignore certain directories?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solution is to use the -i flag. The best way to do this is to create a .conf file. For example, I have the following file defined as `opengrok.conf`:

```
OPENGROK_APP_SERVER=Tomcat
OPENGROK_TOMCAT_BASE=/usr/local/Cellar/tomcat/8.0.21/libexec
OPENGROK_SCAN_DEPTH=4
OPENGROK_VERBOSE=yes
OPENGROK_PROGRESS=yes
IGNORE_PATTERNS="-i f:foo.txt -i *.bar -i d:target -i d:.tox"
```

And run the indexing using:
`OPENGROK_CONFIGURATION=opengrok.conf ./OpenGrok index $SRC_ROOT`

It ignores indexing the file `foo.txt`, all files that match the pattern `*.bar`, and all files in directories named `target` or `.tox`.

Edit credits: [mrenaud](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1553313/mrenaud), [pcas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/777786/pcas)

Comment: Directories must be prefixed with d:

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I don't have enough points to accept your edit, so I update it myself as per your instructions and credited you.

Comment: Slight typo in IGNORE_PATTERNS="-i f:foo.txt -i *.bar -d:target -i d:.tox"
Should read:
IGNORE_PATTERNS="-i f:foo.txt -i *.bar -i d:target -i d:.tox"

Comment: Thank you, @PCas. Fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

Note that https://github.com/oracle/opengrok/pull/1841 renamed IGNORE_PATTERNS to OPENGROK_IGNORE_PATTERNS (in Oct 2017).

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/oracle/opengrok/wiki/How-to-setup-OpenGrok

```
java -jar opengrok-1.3.16/lib/opengrok.jar --help

  -i, --ignore pattern
        Ignore matching files (prefixed with 'f:' or no prefix) or directories
        (prefixed with 'd:'). Pattern supports wildcards (example: -i '*.so'
        -i d:'test*'). Option may be repeated.
```

with the new opengrok-tools, it looks like

```sh
opengrok-indexer                                                           \
    --java_opts=-Djava.util.logging.config.file=$(OPENGROK_BASE)/etc/logging.properties \
    --jar $(OPENGROK_DIST)/lib/opengrok.jar --                                          \
    --ctags /usr/local/bin/ctags                                                        \
    --source $(PWD)                                                                     \
        --dataRoot $(OPENGROK_BASE)/data                                                    \
        --progress                                                                          \
        --history                                                                           \
        --assignTags                                                                        \
    --writeConfig $(OPENGROK_BASE)/etc/configuration.xml                                \
        --analyzer .sc:ScalaAnalyzer                                                        \
        --ignore 'd:zold'                                                                   \
        --ignore 'd:opengrok'                                                               \
        --ignore 'd:tmp'                                                                    \
        --ignore 'd:.venv'                                                                  \
        --ignore 'd:.ipynb_checkpoints'                                                     \
        --ignore 'd:.metals'                                                                \
    # END
```